Array list(Formula) of Supervisor plotted Leave
I have an excel file/tracker of Plotted Vacations of all employees. I want to plot every supervisor that has a vacation on a calendar.
Excel tracker

Calendar

The calendar is also an excel file, im trying to use this code on the names but only showing blanks.
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$I,SMALL(IF(AND($D:$D="Supervisor",$I:$I="Plotted",$C:$C=$P$1),ROW($D:$D)),ROW(1:1)),2),"")}
Anyone can show me how only using formulas?

AND() doesn't work for arrays, it will only output one result, you could replace it with ($D:$D="Supervisor",$I:$I)*("Plotted",$C:$C=$P$1)*$C:$C=$P$1).

wow glad to ask, just a simple problem with excel masters. Thank you Excellor. Ive been working with this for 3days now and just like that you solve it already. Thank you.

I'm not entirely sure where you're using the formula and on how many rows, but you might want to change ROW(1:1) with ROW()-x, where x is your row number you're starting on (so if you start the formula in row 1, just remove it, if you start in row 2, x = -1. If that makes sense.
